# ExtJS adding items that wrap

Tags: javascript, extjs

This seems like a simple question, but I am unable to figure it out. I want to add items (in this case simply buttons) to a panel that will sit side-by-side, but wrap when it gets to the end of the panel...

Thanks,
JJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I came up with was to use a table layout, so then I could just list the items and they would wrap once they reached the end column. But this does not allow for a dynamic number of items in the panel....

Comment: I have a known number of elements, but i want to wrap them if there is not enough space (windows shrinking, low resolution, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to wrap buttons on a panel. Don't you think the there is better ways to have buttons on a panel? We have **toolbars** for that reason! Ext JS provides you will both top and bottom toolbars.

I recommend you make use of these and creating a menu rather than adding buttons directly. This will definitely have better UX than the wrapped buttons on panel.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Abdel. The specs was to have x number of buttons that when they came to the edge would start a new line. Toolbars have the enableOverflow, but unfortunately we have to stick with the specs :(

Comment: but how to make toolbar wraps its elements ??